# ReactJS con Redux, el estado cambia pero el componente no se renderiza

Tags: reactjs, useeffect

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, después de pedir info a mi backend y que este me devolviera un error del tipo "country not found", llamo a un dispatch que mete ese error en un estado de nombre errors que puse en el reducer.

Hasta aquí todo bien, cuando estoy en la pagina en cuestión, hago la busqueda que genera lo que explique anteriormente, veo atraves de redux dev tools que el estado "errors" efectivamente se modifica y viene valorizado.

El problema es que en la pagina no se renderiza.

En la pagina use el siguiente useEffect  pero no funciona.
Alguien me da una mano, please?

`useEffect(()=>{ alert('Error: ', errors); },[errors]);`

Comment: ¿`errors` es un array? En ese caso te diría que lo mejor es que no uses un array como dependencia ya que la referencia al objeto no ha cambiado (aunque su contenido sí lo haya hecho), de ahí que no salte el useEffect. Échale un vistazo a esta solución (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467758/passing-array-to-useeffect-dependency-list) si aún así quieres seguir usando el array. Aquí Dan Abramov habla un poco más de esto: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14476#issuecomment-471199055

Comment: Si pudieras compartir código para poder ayudarte, por ejemplo una version mínima del componente, como estas trayendo el estado `errors` a tu componente (`useSelector`, `store.getState` etc), y como estas armando el componente (`mapStateToProps/mapDispatchToProps`, single `container/presentational`), esos detalles son de utilidad, saludos

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, el problema era que, cuando llamaba al dispatch no le ponía adelante el await, ahora la info se renderiza sin problemas.
Gracias por el interes.
Como hago para marcar la pregunta como resuelta?

Comment: Puedes contestar tu propia pregunta, si pudieras agregar todo ese código donde dices que faltaba el `dispatch`, me gustaria verlo ya que no he visto el uso de `async/await` directamente en `disptach`, saludos